# Code works despite implemented methods having the same signature

Tags: c#, interface

I didn't realise why this code work ?

```
interface ISumCalculator
{
    int Calc( int x, int y );
}

interface IProductCalculator
{
    int Clac ( int x, int y );
}


class Calculator : ISumCalculator, IProductCalculator
{

    public int Calc(int x, int y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Clac(int x, int y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm... they have different names?

Comment: One is `Calc` and the other is `Clac`.

Comment: For consistency, i would suggest renaming the IProductCalculator interface to iProductClaculator though.

Comment: If the names matched, you could still make `Calculator` implement both, using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These methods have same signatures, but *different names*, so there is no issue here.

And even in case of the *exactly* same name and signature you can easilly overcome problem by explicitly defining an interface in definition of the method :

```
class Calculator : ISumCalculator, IProductCalculator
{

    int IProductCalculator.Calc(int x, int y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int ISumCalculator.Calc(int x, int y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calc()` and `Clac()` are two different method names.